# How to solve DEVELOPER_TOKEN_PROHIBITED error while requesting google Ads Api?

Tags: google-ads-api

To request Google Ads API v1, we use oauth2 flow, using client_id/client_secret created in GCP interface and refresh_token associated with our account on google Adwords interface from google oauth2 playground.

We are trying to update our developper token as we obtained a standard access.
We were requesting Google Adwords API with no troubles with a previous API token associated with another MCC account, and the same gcp project.

Now that we change the API token, we are receiving DEVELOPER_TOKEN_PROHIBITED "Developer token 'XXXXX' is not allowed with project 'XXXXX'.

Could you please tell us which relationship lies between API token and gcp project ?
Any hints about how to solve that issue ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

For a given Google Cloud project ID, the Google Ads API only allows you to use one developer token.

The `DEVELOPER_TOKEN_PROHIBITED` error indicates that in the past, there was at least one request to your Google Ads API using OAuth credentials from the same project ID but different developer token.

The best way to resolve this issue is to create a new Google Cloud Project ID, obtain a new OAuth2 credentials from a client under the new project ID, and use those credentials in your requests with your developer token.